# How do I extract using PowerShell the ErrorCode & ErrorDescription from this XML?

Tags: xml, powershell, namespaces

I am struggling a lot with trying to get the values of ErrorCode & ErrorDescription from the following XML:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

have tried the below, it is working but seems to me like the bad working way:

```
cls

$res = [xml]@'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
'@


$XPath = "/ns:Envelope/ns:Body"

[xml]$xml = $res
$namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
$ns.AddNamespace("nsa", "http://tempuri.org/")
$ns.AddNamespace("nsb", "http://tempuri.org/")
$product = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $ns)

Write-Host $product

#exit


$XPath = "/ns:Envelope/ns:Body"


[xml]$xml = $res
$namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
$product = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $ns)
#Write-Host $product.InnerXml


#$newres = [xml]@'
#<ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLS
#chema-instance"><a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode><a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription></ActionResult></ActionResponse>
#'@

[xml]$newres = $product.InnerXml

$XPath = "/ns:ActionResponse"

[xml]$xml = $newres
$namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
$product = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $ns)


$XPath = "/ns:ActionResult" 

[xml]$xml = $product.InnerXml
$namespace = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $namespace)
$product = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath, $ns)

Write-Host "ErrCode: ",$product.ErrorCode ," ErrDesc: ",$product.ErrorDescription
Write-Host $product.ErrorCode, $product.ErrorDescription
```

I guess the reason for the difficult to get the values is due to the name spaces used here (several)
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: If you want to use an XPATH but ignore namespaces, then you can use the XPATH `local-name()` function. `$XPath = '//*[local-name()="ActionResult"]'`.

Comment: I think that I cannot ignore the name spaces as this xnl is a resu of running a web service, unless I'm missing something here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Frenchy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67676597/11025476) if you do not care about namespaces or using XPATH.

---

If you do not care about namespace but must use XPATH, you may utilize the `local-name()` function.

```
$res = [xml]@'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
'@

$XPath = '//*[local-name() = "ErrorCode" or local-name() = "ErrorDescription"]'

$Nodes = (Select-Xml -Xml $res -XPath $XPath).Node
$Nodes # Your Xml elements
```

---

If you want to use the defined namespaces and XPATH, you may do the following:

```
$res = [xml]@'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
'@
$XPath = '/s:Envelope/s:Body/NSWithNoName:ActionResponse/NSWithNoName:ActionResult/a:*["ErrorCode" or "ErrorDescription"]'

$ns = @{ a = 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes'
         s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                                                                                                                                   
         NSWithNoName = "http://tempuri.org/"
}

$Nodes = (Select-Xml -Xml $res -XPath $XPath -Namespace $ns).Node
$Nodes # Your xml elements ErrorCode and ErrorDescription
```

Here you have a namespace definition with no name assigned. Since we are using a hash table to manage the namespaces, it is best to give it a name/key in that hash table. You can then reference the hash table key name in the XPATH expression.

You can modify the XPATH to select the `ActionResult` node(s) instead. Then use another `Select-Xml` with a different XPATH to select the `ErrorCode` and `ErrorDescription` nodes.

```
$XPath = '/s:Envelope/s:Body/NSWithNoName:ActionResponse/NSWithNoName:ActionResult'

$ARNode = (Select-Xml -Xml $res -XPath $XPath -Namespace $ns).Node
$ECNode = (Select-Xml -Xml $ARNode -XPath './a:ErrorCode' -Namespace $ns).Node
$EDNode = (Select-Xml -Xml $ARNode -XPath './a:ErrorDescription' -Namespace $ns).Node
```

Comment: This solution looks good, I will try it (but only next week) and will update., many thanks for this detailed answer

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response and thanks again for this detailed solution, tried the first one, it failed since the $ns is not defined, not sure how to define it, but then checked the 2nd and it worked as magic, then took the definition of $ns from the 2nd and placed it on the 1st and it also made it to work., bottom line, you have solved it :), many thanks for that!!

Answer (score 0):

you just follow the way :

```
cls

$res = [xml]@'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
'@

$errorCode = $res.Envelope.Body.ActionResponse.ActionResult.ErrorCode
$ErrorDescription = $res.Envelope.Body.ActionResponse.ActionResult.ErrorDescription
```

if you could have more ActionResponses use this code:

```
cls

$res = [xml]@'
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>1</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
      <ActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RL.Common.CommonTypes" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:ErrorCode>2</a:ErrorCode>
            <a:ErrorDescription>General2 Error</a:ErrorDescription>
         </ActionResult>
      </ActionResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
'@

$actResponses = $res.Envelope.Body.ChildNodes
foreach($act in $actResponses){
 "Error code :" + $act.ActionResult.ErrorCode + " Description: " + $act.ActionResult.ErrorDescription
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this approach but it returns nothing...

Comment: i dont see why is not functional, what is your version of powershell?

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay in response, I am using version: 5.1.18362.1171